# Programmatically generate SQL script to create database without PRIMARY statement .. using scripter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sql-scripts

I have create script which is automatically generated by `Scripter.Script()` method.
But if want to get rid of file paths included in the script. Which property is need to be set while using Scripter class to generate script ?

SQL Script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [ContactManager] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'ContactManager', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ContactManager.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'ContactManager_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ContactManager.ldf' , SIZE = 5184KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

but now I want to generate script without primary statement like below:

```
CREATE DATABASE [ContactManager] GO
```

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE ContactManager;` is a valid statement. The primary statement is optional. If you dont specify the file names SQL will just use the database name.

Comment: @NathanSkerl kindly refer the edited question

Answer (score 4):

`ScriptingOptions.NoFileGroup` should suppress the additional filegroup clauses.

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.nofilegroup.aspx).

Also, it seems that simply calling `db.Script()` without the property enabled omits the filegroup anyways, so I am not positive this will work for you without seeing your code.

See my example below:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server srv = new Server(".");
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db = new Database(srv, "Yak");       

System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection statements = db.Script();

Console.WriteLine(statements);

ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions();
so.NoFileGroup = false;


foreach (string s in db.Script(so))
{
      Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```